# Finding a circumscribed circle around a plane compact set

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

This question is based on R. Osserman's proof of the four-vertex-theorem (see here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609268.pdf ).

Without explaining anything, neither in the original work of Mr. Ossermann, nor in the above cited paper is there a proof for the claim that there exists a minimal circle around a compact set. Of course, assuming that it exists it's easy to see why it is unique, but the existence itself is, according to my intuition, hard.

My own tries:

Consider the compact set $E$ and the set $\mathfrak{D}$ of all closed discs, such that $\forall D \in \mathfrak{D} : D \supseteq E$.

Let $(D_i)_{i \in I}$ be a decreasing family of closed discs in $\mathfrak{D}$. It's enough to show that $D:= \cap _{i\in I} D_i \in \mathfrak{D}$, because then it's shown that each monotonically decreasing sequence of discs has its minimum, therefore with Zorn's Lemma, there would exist a global minimum.

It follows immediately that $D$ is compact and $D \supseteq E$, as $\forall i \in I : D_i \supseteq E $. To show is, that $D$ is a disc.

Assuming $D$ wouldn't be a disc, then for any disc $D$', the set $\tilde{D} := D \Delta D' $ with the symmetric difference operator Delta wouldn't be empty.

Form here I have no idea how to get the contradiction.

Note: I didn't get any hints for how to do it, I'm just reading Ossermann's paper.

If there is a simpler or better proof, I'd like to get the source, as it's not obvious to me like Ossermann states it.

Comment: Please enclose your formulas by $ from both sides, so that your text is friendly to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Let $r = \inf$ of radiuses of discs containing $A$. Consider a sequence of discs $D(c_n, r_n)$ containing $A$, with $r_n \to r$. Now, $c_n$ is a bounded sequence (why?), so it has a convergent subsequence. We may assume $c_n$ convergent to $c$. Recall that $r_n$ convergent to $r$, and $D(c_n, r_n)$ contains $A$. Now show that $D(c, r)$ contains $A$.

Comment: Ah. Thank you very much. I didn't think that way. ```$(c_n)$``` is bounded, as we can assume, that we consider a sequence of discs, that are contained in a larger disc, which contains our compact set. I'll try to show that the limit discs contains the compact set.

Comment: Is it possible to say, that if x is not in D(c,r), then there exists an epsilon>0 such that D(x, epsilon) is completely outside D(c,r). There exist N, N', such that for all n>max(N, N'): ||cn - c|| < epsilon/3 and |rn - r| < epsilon/3 therefore there exists an m, such that x is not contained in D(cm, rm) which means, that x is not in A, due to the definition of D(cm, rm).?

Comment: @user850413: Consider a point $a$ in $A$. We have $d(c_n, a) \le r_n$, and now take the limit as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: @user850413: Now, the disc of smallest radius is such that its radius cannot be decreased. It has to contain on its boundary $3$ points of $A$ such that the triangle contains the centre. Thus, it is the minimal disc for a subset of $3$ points of $A$.

Comment: @user850413: Took a look at the paper, looks very interesting.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you very much.